# Order by tablename?

Tags: sql

Is there any way to use the "order" function on your table name. i.e I want to union two tables then sort by the one column, then by table name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add constant to your column list that describes your table name, E.g.

```
select *, 'TableA' as TableName
from TableA
union all
select *, 'TableB' as TableName
from TableB
order by TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate column (assuming that your columns are `col1` and `col2`)

```
select col1,col2,table_1 as table_name
from table_1
union
select col1,col2,table_2 as table_name
from table_2
order by col1,table_name;
```